# Regular expression tokenization with numbers?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I am expecting the following code;
tokenize

```
this is an example 123
```

into

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example 123']
```

but it doesn't see numbers part of the word. Any suggestion?

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
pattern=re.compile(r"[\w\s\d]+")
tokenizer_number=RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
tokenizer_number.tokenize("this is an example 123")
```

Comment: Use `split()` instead?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619297/how-to-prevent-splitting-specific-words-or-phrases-and-numbers-in-nltk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty well formed regex :

```
[\d.,]+|[A-Z][.A-Z]+\b\.*|\w+|\S
```

This topic was solved before in : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144991/nltk-nltk-tokenize-regexptokenizer-regex-not-working-as-expected)!

,You can test regex interactively with https://regex101.com

Comment: This pattern works: pattern=r'[\w]+[\s]+[\d?]+[\w]|\w+\S'

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.split()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm):

```
s = "this is an example 123"    
print(s.split(" ", 3))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example 123']
```

Comment: This is hardcoded to solve only that example; it won't work in general cases at all

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. You are matching any sequence of letters, digits or spaces. You meant this instead:

```
pattern=re.compile(r"\w+\s\d+|\w+")
```

Or equivalently, you could write that as `r"\w+(?:\s\d+)?"`.